# I am trying to create a IF/AND/OR statement in SharePoint, but it's not capturing what I need it to

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

The formula I have now is:

```
=IF(AND([Add or Remove]="Add",[RealPage Complete]="No",OR([Add or Remove]="Terminate",[RealPage Complete]="No",[CMP Contact Unmapped]="Yes")),"VC Review Needed","")
```

What I am trying to capture is:

```
IF:
-Add or Remove=Add
And
-RealPage Complete=No
Then the column should read "VC Review Needed"

OR:
-Add or Remove=Terminate
And
-RealPage Complete=No
And
-CMP Contact Unmapped=Yes
Then the column should be blank
```

As of now, all columns show blank. Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood from your formula, here is the revised formula:

More info on formulas can be found at [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))

```
IF(

OR(

AND([Add or Remove]="Add",[RealPage Complete]="No"),

AND(AND([Add or Remove]="Terminate",[RealPage Complete]="No"),[CMP Contact Unmapped]="Yes")

)

,"VC Review Needed","")
```